# Cannot send multiple email Yii2

Tags: php, yii2, swiftmailer

I working with framework Yii2 and I want send mail with [Mailing](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/tutorial-mailing). 1 email address sent successfully but array email address sent fail and Show error message:

Exception 'Swift_RfcComplianceException' with message 'Address in mailbox given [xxx@gmail.com,xxx@gmail.com] does not comply with RFC 2822, 3.6.2.'

My code send mail:

```
Yii::$app->mailer->setTransport([
                    'class' => 'Swift_SmtpTransport',
                    'host' => 'smtp.gmail.com',
                    'username' => $valueEmailSystem->username_mail,
                    'password' => $valueEmailSystem->password_mail,
                    'port' => $valueEmailSystem->port,
                    'encryption' => 'tls',
                ]);

$message = Yii::$app->mailer->compose();
            $message->setFrom([$valueEmailSystem->username_mail => 'TEST']);
            $str = implode(',', (array)$modelUser);
            $message->setBcc($str);
            $message->setSubject('Xác nhận yêu cầu');
            $strUserName = implode(',', (array)User::getNameById($pk));
            foreach ($valueContent as $key => $item) {
                $reValue = str_replace("[hoten]",$strUserName,$item->value);
                $message->setHtmlBody($reValue);
            }
            $message->send();
```

Help me! Thank all.

Comment: The error is clear, try to read this [https://github.com/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/issues/382](https://github.com/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/issues/382)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are imploding the addresses into one string. The `setBcc()` method accepts one address as string or multiple addresses as array, for example like that:

```php
$message->setBcc(['first@example.com', 'second@example.com']);
```

Or if you want to specify names

```php
$message->setBcc([
   'first@example.com' => 'First Person',
   'second@example.com' => 'Second Person',
]);
```

[Documentation of method](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-mail-messageinterface#setBcc()-detail).